# How to join 2 elements with opacity to look like one?

Tags: css

I need to make a tooltip and I'm clashed with a problem. Now I have this:
[image: Tooltip]

You can see that arrow and rectangle don't look like one element. They're both pseudo-elements of common parent element:

```
<div class="progress__control progress__control_to_next">
    ::before   <!-- rectangle -->
    <!-- ... -->
    ::after   <!-- arrow -->
</div>
```

Their styles:

```
.progress__control {
    color: #ffffff;

    &::before {
        content: 'Завершить этап';
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: -26px;
        width: 80px;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        padding: 3px 6px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: rgba(48, 63, 79, 0.9);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: -9px;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent; 
        border-top: 6px solid rgba(48, 63, 79, 0.9);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make it looks like one element?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `z-index` of the `::after` to higher than the `::before`?

Comment: @JamesLong yes, however, I think, because of opacity it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: simply don't make them to overlap, adjust position

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, I tried it, I moved arrow by one pixel down and there was a little space between them.

Comment: Is some of the CSS missing? looks like the main problem is the shadow around the box element -- which I don't know a fix for, but without it the elements should look solid together... when I copied the CSS into the snippet tool, it looked as expected (without a shadow)

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] with it? It would be so much easier to provide advice if we could actually inspect and debug it.

Comment: Does it need to be a pseudo element - why not just use a span, then the arrow can be part of the span and you can use a drop shadow instead of a box shadow

Comment: @Doug Hmm, there is no css missing. They don't have box-shadow property.

Comment: I tried creating a snippet from what you posted and it doesn't look like that. Where is the `color:white` coming from? Where is the `box-shadow` coming from? You probably have a tooltip plugin embedded in your library that's changing those on the fly. If you're not able to find out the source of that CSS by yourself, the only way we can help is if you reproduce the issue here.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu ok, I'll add parent element styles to the question.

Comment: Add whatever is necessary for your issue to be reproduce-able. If it's not **nobody** can help, because **nobody** can test a potential fix to it. I'd say adding parent element styles is unlikely to help here, because tooltip styles are usually placed in the tooltip plugin/function, not in parent element.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu This tooltip is written completely by me. Color: white as you can see comes from parent element and there is no box-shadow property. To be sure in it I added box-shadow: none and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you provide info on which browsers (and operating systems) in which you see the result pictured?

Comment: @Doug Windows 10 Home Edition, the latest Google Chrome

Comment: Ok, so I think I have been able to replicate -- depending on how the psuedo-elements are positioned, they can overlap slightly.  So with the color opacity (rgba) and the element opacity, where the elements overlap the colors combine into a darker color.  Easiest fix, use solid colors -- drop the opacities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the separate opacities on the psuedo-elements (and their background colors), there's a chance where sometimes the elements will overlap, creating a darker color.

Remove the opacity and rgba, in favor of solid colors.

Potentially, you can adjust the opacity on the parent element itself, with less of an occurrence of the overlapped colors...

```css
.progress__control{
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.progress__control::before {
    content: 'Завершить этап';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 3px 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(48, 63, 79, 1);
}

.progress__control::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 73px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 6px solid rgba(48, 63, 79, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress__control"></div>
```

Here's an example that blows things out of proportion to test if the overlap still occurs...

```css
body{background-color: #EEF; }

.progress__control{
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.progress__control::after {
    content: 'Завершить этап';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(48, 63, 79, 1);
}

.progress__control::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 70px solid rgba(48, 63, 79, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress__control"></div>
```

Comment: It really helps when I moved opacity property to parent element. After this they overlap without making a color darker. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make the pseduo-element "arrow" from a square element and apply a clip path.

Then you can use a background color rather than boder.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress__control {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(48, 63, 79, 0.9);
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(48, 63, 79, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

.progress__control::before {
  content: "Завершить этап";
}

.progress__control::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: inherit;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress__control">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have height for the :before specified.. so it is calculated from font size.. which I assume is not an integer in pixels due to some other calculations.
And as experiment shown height of this element differs between browsers.. if not specified. So again depends on font size.

I was able to modify your code in a way that produces the desired result. But you'll have to figure out values for yourself.

[image]

https://codepen.io/Alexander-Taran/pen/JBpJKw

html:

```
;lkj;lkj;lkj
lkj;lkj<br>
<br>

<div class="progress__control progress__control_to_next">

  asdasdaasdasd

</div>
kjhlkjhlkjh
lkjhlkjh
```

scss:

```
body{
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);  
}
.progress__control {
    color: #ffffff;
position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
    &:before {
        content: 'Завершить этап';
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: -26px;
        height:26px;
        width: 180px;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        padding: 3px 6px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: rgba(48, 63, 79, 0.9);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0px;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent; 
        border-top: 6px solid rgba(48, 63, 79, 0.9);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just play with line height (below 18px is just example) adjust value as per requirement.. will be OK

[CAN CHECK HERE](https://codepen.io/tara-sankar/pen/zLRdBO)

```
*::after,*::before{
             line-height: 18px; 

          }
```